# Read COM using C++ in open source game client

Tags: c++, serial-port, boost-asio

I have a device that sends a signal every second to the COM5 port. The signal is an integer between 0 and 100. The number changes at a maximum of +3 or -3.
Next. On Github is open source project. It's called OTClientV8. And it is written in C++
I want to add code to this client that will read the COM5 port.
using boost::asio.
At first, I would like to make the value from the device appear in the terminal(in client) every second. (Later I will try to display the value in the player's skills and send it to the server - because it is an MMO.)
I have some code that I don't even know if it's written well - I'm a Python programmer(without experience in SerialPorts) and I'm just learning C++.
Could someone tell me if the code below makes sense?
The code is partially copied from another module of this client, modified, improved with bard and gpt chat. The game client compiles but nothing related to the new code is displayed.
COM5 keeps sending numbers 0-100 because I checked it with a small python program.
Windows platform
Here is the code:

i created 2 new files:

com.cpp

```
#include <boost/asio/read.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include "framework/global.h"
#include "com.h"

COM g_com;

COM::COM() : port(io_service, "COM5") {
    // Configure serial port settings
    port.set_option(boost::asio::serial_port_base::baud_rate(9600));
    port.set_option(boost::asio::serial_port_base::character_size(8));
    port.set_option(boost::asio::serial_port_base::parity(boost::asio::serial_port_base::parity::none));
    port.set_option(boost::asio::serial_port_base::stop_bits(boost::asio::serial_port_base::stop_bits::one));
    port.set_option(boost::asio::serial_port_base::flow_control(boost::asio::serial_port_base::flow_control::none));
}

void COM::startAsyncRead() {
    // Asynchronously read data into the buffer
    boost::asio::async_read_until(port, buffer, '\n',
        [this](boost::system::error_code error, std::size_t bytes_transferred) {
            if (!error) {
                // Process the received data
                std::istream is(&buffer);
                std::string line;
                std::getline(is, line);
                g_logger.info(stdext::format("This is my output from com: %s", line));

                // Continue asynchronous reading
                startAsyncRead();
            } else {
                // Error handling
                std::cerr << "Error reading from serial port: " << error.message() << std::endl;
            }
        });
}

void COM::init() {
    // Start asynchronous reading in a separate thread
    asyncThread = std::thread([this] {
        io_service.run();
    });

    // Start the first asynchronous read
    startAsyncRead();
}

void COM::terminate() {
    // Stop the io_service and join the thread
    io_service.stop();
    asyncThread.join();
    g_logger.info("Bye!");
}
```

and next file:
com.h

```
#ifndef COM_H
#define COM_H

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <thread>

class COM {
public:
    COM(); // Constructor
    void init();
    void terminate();

private:
    void startAsyncRead();

private:
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    boost::asio::serial_port port;
    boost::asio::streambuf buffer;
    std::thread asyncThread;
};

extern COM g_com;

#endif
```

and in client in file client.cpp

i add 2 lines

```
Client g_client;

void Client::init(std::vector<std::string>& args)
{
    // register needed lua functions
    registerLuaFunctions();

    g_map.init();
    g_minimap.init();
    g_game.init();
    g_shaders.init();
    g_things.init();
    g_healthBars.init();
    g_com.init(); /-- i added 

}

void Client::terminate()
{
    g_creatures.terminate();
    g_game.terminate();
    g_map.terminate();
    g_minimap.terminate();
    g_things.terminate();
    g_sprites.terminate();
    g_shaders.terminate();
    g_healthBars.terminate();
    g_com.terminate();  / -- i added
}
```

I know that there is no loop in the code(com.cpp) to read the values every second. At the beginning, I would like the code to display "anything", preferably the value from COM5. I'll try to loop it later

I know that the game client reads "init" and "terminate" because yesterday I experimented with displaying "Hello World" in the in-game terminal using "g_logger.info("Hello, world!");" and it worked.

My questions:

1. Is this code a "good way" to achieve this goal, i.e. reading COM in c++?
2. Why doesn't this code display anything in the terminal?

I don't know, maybe my questions are too general, but if you can help, thank you

edit. code is working, chat gpt write for me this.

Comment: Have you tried using Windows `CreateFile` using `COM5` as the filename?  It has worked for me.

Comment: In my system there is COM5 and it transmits numbers. It's an Arduino programmed  to generate numbers

Comment: I haven't tried CreateFile but to read COM with boost::asio is a bad idea?

Comment: I used CreateFile without `boost::asio`.

Comment: I wanted to use boost::asio for my own reasons.
The first one is that the entire client is based and requires boost, so I thought I would use boost. And secondly, when I want to create a client for Linux in the far future, will CreateFile will be good for reading COM?
But I will try as you recommend(CreateFile)

Comment: it's funny, but I copied the entire post I wrote on stackoverflow to chat gpt and it nicely wrote me the code that will start working in a loop

Comment: @DoDr what's funnier is that you didn't post the answer...

Answer (score 1):

I think all the code is a red herring, and the only relevant information here is:

```
// COM5 keeps sending numbers 0-100 because I checked it with a small python program
```

It would have helped to see *that* python program, because now we have to assume things (like, protocol, baudrate, parity etc.). Let's assume some things and line-wise text format:

```cpp
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using Port     = asio::serial_port;

int main() {
    asio::io_context ioc;
    Port sp(ioc, "COM5:");

    sp.set_option(Port::baud_rate(115200));
    //// Potentially other options
    // sp.set_option(Port::flow_control(Port::flow_control::hardware));
    // sp.set_option(Port::stop_bits(Port::stop_bits::one));
    // sp.set_option(Port::parity(Port::parity::odd));

    std::string buf;
    for (boost::system::error_code ec; auto n = read_until(sp, asio::dynamic_buffer(buf), "\n", ec);) {
        if (n) {
            std::string_view message(buf.data(), n - 1);
            std::cout << "received " << std::quoted(message) << std::endl;
            buf.erase(0, n);
        } else {
            std::cout << "received empty buffer (" << ec.message() << ")" << std::endl;
        }
        if (ec.failed())
            break;
    }
}
```

Simple demonstration (not on windows, but it will behave the same):

[image]

### What If?

What if it's binary? What if the packets are variable length and you want to get them as soon as they are made available by the serial port driver?

```
std::array<uint8_t, 1024> buf;
for (boost::system::error_code ec; auto n = sp.read_some(asio::buffer(buf), ec);) {
    if (n) {
        fmt::print("Received {::#02x}\n", std::span(buf.data(), n));
    } else {
        fmt::print("Received empty buffer ({})\n", ec.message());
    }
    if (ec.failed())
        break;
}
```

Now we get, e.g.:

[image]

Note how when we stop and restart the program, it receives all available data on the serial interface at once.

Comment: I see now the options could have been gleaned from your code (I kind of ignored it since there was no `Client` code, sorry. Self-contained code works on StackOverflow)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.
I have a problem because after trying to read Arduino using python, regardless of how long the Arduino "works", the reading (with Python) always starts with the same number and it should be different. Is this related to the example you describe?

Comment: It's hard (actually impossible) to tell without seeing the python code (and potentially knowing what the device sends)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77925953/random-number-generator-on-arduino-and-repeatability-of-readings -- here is full code