# Read COM port with the boost::asio library. I cannot resume reading data

Tags: c++, serial-port, boost-asio

I want to make a module for the game client to read COM5 with the boost::asio library. I need a function that will disable the port from reading and include values in reading (from the Arduino device). I have a module written in C++ and some of it bound to Lua, but it's mainly C++ code because there is an error at this stage.

this is my com.cpp

// com.cpp

```
#include <boost/asio/read.hpp>
#include "com.h"
#include "./client/protocolgame.h"
#include "./client/game.h"

COM g_com;

COM::COM() : port(io_service, "COM5") {
    configureSerialPort();
}

void COM::configureSerialPort() {
    // Configure serial port settings
    port.set_option(boost::asio::serial_port_base::baud_rate(9600));
    port.set_option(boost::asio::serial_port_base::character_size(8));
    port.set_option(boost::asio::serial_port_base::parity(boost::asio::serial_port_base::parity::none));
    port.set_option(boost::asio::serial_port_base::stop_bits(boost::asio::serial_port_base::stop_bits::one));
    port.set_option(boost::asio::serial_port_base::flow_control(boost::asio::serial_port_base::flow_control::none));
}

void COM::startAsyncRead() {
    g_logger.info("step:1");
    // Asynchronously read data into the buffer
    boost::asio::async_read_until(port, buffer, '\n',
        [this](boost::system::error_code error, std::size_t bytes_transferred) {
            if (!error) {
                g_logger.info("step:2");
                // Process the received data
                std::string line;
                std::istream is(&buffer);
                std::getline(is, line);
                try {
                    g_logger.info("step:3");
                    int value = std::stoi(line);
                    m_Data = value;
                    g_logger.info(stdext::format("Received data: %d", value));
                }

                catch (const std::exception& e) {
                    g_logger.info("step:4");

                    g_logger.info(stdext::format("Error converting received data to integer: %d", e.what()));
                    std::cerr << "Error converting received data to integer: " << e.what() << std::endl;
                }
                // Continue asynchronous reading
                buffer.consume(buffer.size());
                g_logger.info("step:5");

                startAsyncRead();
            }
            else {
                // Error handling
                g_logger.info("step:6");

                g_logger.info(stdext::format("Error reading from serial port: ", error.message()));

                std::cerr << "Error reading from serial port: " << error.message() << std::endl;
            }
        });
}

void COM::initialize() {
    // Start asynchronous reading in a separate thread if the connection is already established
    if (port.is_open() && m_Enabled && !m_AlreadyConnected) {
        // Add a short delay before starting to read data
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));

        startAsyncRead();

        // Set the flag indicating that the device is already connected
        m_AlreadyConnected = true;

        g_logger.info("Device is connected");
    }
}

void COM::setEnabled(bool enable) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);

    // Check if the device is already in the desired state
    if (m_Enabled == enable)
        return;

    // Update device state
    m_Enabled = enable;

    // If we want to disable the device
    if (!enable) {
        // Stop the asynchronous thread and wait for its completion
        if (asyncThread.joinable()) {
            io_service.stop();
            asyncThread.join();
        }
    }
    // If we want to enable the device
    else {
        // Start the asynchronous thread only if the device is enabled
        if (m_Enabled) {
            // Initialize the device if not already done
            if (!m_AlreadyConnected) {
                initialize();
            }

            // Start the asynchronous thread
            asyncThread = std::thread([this] {
                io_service.run();
                });

            // Start the first asynchronous read
            startAsyncRead();
        }
    }
}

void COM::terminate() {
    // Stop the io_service and join the thread
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        m_Enabled = false;

        // Reset the flag indicating that the device is already connected
        m_AlreadyConnected = false;
    }
    io_service.stop();
    if (asyncThread.joinable())
        asyncThread.join();
    g_logger.info("Bye!");
}
```

In client in terminal i have:

```
step:1
Device is connected
step:1
EEG is:     true
step:2
step:3
Received data: 50
step:5
step:1
step:2
step:3
Received data: 59
step:5
step:1
step:2
step:3
Received data: 60
step:5
step:1
step:2
step:3
Received data: 61
step:5
step:1
step:2
step:3
Received data: 62
step:5
step:1
step:2
step:3
Received data: 63
step:5
step:1
step:2
step:3
Received data: 64
step:5
step:1
step:2
step:3
Received data: 65
step:5
step:1
Bye! <-- i push buton to off
EEG is:     false
step:1  <-- i push buton to on
Device is connected
step:1
EEG is:     true
Bye!
EEG is:     false
step:1
Device is connected
step:1
EEG is:     true
step:2
step:3
Received data: 66
step:5
step:1
step:2
step:3
Received data: 67
step:5
step:1
Bye!
EEG is:     false
```

How to stop reading COM5 with boost::asio and how to resume it?

Comment: Seems like you're (mis)using this async I/O capability to perform "ordinary" blocking I/O. Since you seem to want/need to wait for the input to arrive/complete, why even bother using async I/O?

Comment: "*In client in terminal i have: ... step:1 ... Device is connected ... step:1*" - The very start of your log looks like a bug. This seems to indicate that **async_read_until()** is invoked a *second* (and invalid) time before its handler is ever called (which would be indicated by a `step:2` or `step:6` line. That means that there is always at least one **async_read_until()** operation active once your programs starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm. You use the composed read `read_until`, whithout ever paying attention to the `bytes_transferred` value. [That's just broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058589/boostasioasync-read-until-reads-all-data-instead-of-just-some). You're taking the first value encountered (even if you received another 100 values at the same time) and then just discard the entire rest of the buffer.

I've [already shown you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77923757/85371) how to reliably use the composed read operation with dynamic buffers (just like `asio::streambuf`, but it doesn't need to be, as you can see below):

```
std::string buf;
for (boost::system::error_code ec; auto n = read_until(sp, asio::dynamic_buffer(buf), "\n", ec);) {
    if (n) {
        std::string_view message(buf.data(), n - 1);
        std::cout << "received " << std::quoted(message) << std::endl;
        buf.erase(0, n);
    } else {
        std::cout << "received empty buffer (" << ec.message() << ")" << std::endl;
    }
    if (ec.failed())
        break;
}
```

Now, apparently there's a need to have this asynchronous (I doubt it, I'd instead use `read_some` from the tick routine that you probably have). Also, you don't show how you control the reads, but from the comments it appears that the stacktrace indicates that you're calling `startAsyncRead` multiple times. That's wrong. It's unneeded and leads to Undefined Behaviour because it violates the [contract](https://beta.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read_until/overload1.html):

> The program must ensure that the stream performs no other read operations (such as async_read, async_read_until, the stream's async_read_some function, or any other composed operations that perform reads) until this operation completes.

A few other things raise concerns, like thread safety and race conditions. Let me address them with another live demo:

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/06d527f177e0e983)**

```cpp
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using std::this_thread::sleep_for;

// mocking question code
struct {
    void info(std::string const& msg) const {
        static auto const start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

        auto ts = (std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - start);
        if (ts > 1s)
            std::cout << std::setw(6) << ts / 1.s << "s  " << msg << std::endl;
        else
            std::cout << std::setw(6) << ts / 1ms << "ms " << msg << std::endl;
    }
} static g_logger;
// end mocks

struct COM {
    asio::thread_pool m_ioc{1};
    asio::serial_port m_port{m_ioc};
    std::atomic_int   m_Data = 0;

    std::weak_ptr<void> m_readoperation; // only when read operation active

    void ReadLoop(std::shared_ptr<std::string> buffer = {}) {
        if (!buffer) {
            assert(m_readoperation.expired()); // do not post overlapping read operations
            buffer          = std::make_shared<std::string>();
            m_readoperation = buffer;
        }

        async_read_until(
            m_port, asio::dynamic_buffer(*buffer), '\n',
            [this, buffer](boost::system::error_code ec, size_t n) {
                try {
                    if (n) {
                        int value = std::stoi(buffer->substr(0, n - 1));
                        // g_logger.info("ReadLoop: received " + std::to_string(value));
                        m_Data.store(value);
                        buffer->erase(0, n);
                    }

                    if (!ec.failed())
                        ReadLoop(buffer);
                    else
                        g_logger.info("ReadLoop: " + ec.message());
                } catch (std::exception const& e) {
                    g_logger.info("Error converting received data to integer: " + std::string(e.what()));
                    // considered a stopping problem
                }
            });
    }

    void initialize(bool enable = true) {
        sleep_for(100ms);

        m_port.open("COM5");

        // Configure serial port settings
        using P = asio::serial_port;
        m_port.set_option(P::baud_rate(9600));
        m_port.set_option(P::character_size(8));
        m_port.set_option(P::parity(P::parity::none));
        m_port.set_option(P::stop_bits(P::stop_bits::one));
        m_port.set_option(P::flow_control(P::flow_control::none));

        g_logger.info("Connected");

        setEnabled(enable);
    }

    void setEnabled(bool enable) {
        if (enable == !m_readoperation.expired())
            return; // nothing to do

        if (!enable)
            m_port.cancel(); // cancels read operation (asio::error::operation_aborted)
        else
            ReadLoop();
    }

    void terminate() {
        setEnabled(false);
        g_logger.info("Bye!");
    }
};

// demo code
int main() {
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2);
    g_logger.info("Demo start");
    COM g_com;

    g_com.initialize(false);

    for (auto i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        sleep_for(3.5s);
        g_logger.info("Main thread observed atomic int value: " + to_string(g_com.m_Data));

        bool enable = i % 2; // enable if odd, disable if even
        g_logger.info(enable ? "Enabling read operation" : "Disabling read operation");
        g_com.setEnabled(i % 2);
    }

    g_com.terminate();
}
```

[image]

Comment: In the spirit of writing minimal code, I don't know why `terminate` exists. Also, as a late improvement, consider making `ReadLoop` private so it cannot be misused.